# Convert NaN value into null when parsing json using jackson library

Tags: java, jackson, nan

What is the best way to parse a json string in to a JsonNode object, and convert all the NaN value in to null ? The following code will convert the Nan to DoubleNode NaN. I try to register a custom deserializer but it didn't pick up the Nan node.

```
JsonMapper mapper =  JsonMapper.builder()
            .enable(JsonReadFeature.ALLOW_NON_NUMERIC_NUMBERS).build();

final String testJson =  "{\"key\":NaN}";
JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(testJson)
```

Comment: `{"key":NaN}` is not valid JSON. It is somewhat surprising that it is parsed without error.

Answer (score 0):

One way it could be done is like below

1. Create some POJO class  with **@JsonSetter**  on setter method.

```
    public class KeyPojo {
    
        private Double key;
    
        @JsonSetter
        public void setKey(Double key) {
            if (Double.isNaN(key)) {
                this.key = null;
            } else {
                this.key = key;
            }
        }
    }
```

2. And parse json text like below.

```
    KeyPojo keyObj = mapper.readValue(testJson, KeyPojo.class);
```

now, keyObj.key  contains NULL value.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to able to process any  format of json.